# tsc doesn't move html resources

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, electron, tsc

I am building an electron app in vscode, and when I build it, it builds out to `build/main.js`. In my electron app I am loading an html file like so:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/resources/views/index.html`);
```

But when the application builds the html file doesn't go into the `build` directory.

So, Is there a way with `tsc` that will move those files, or do I have to place the files there manually?

Comment: tsc is only meant to compile typescript code (and maybe some js) it is not a packaging or build system. There are other tools for that.

Comment: For example, you can have a look at [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/) with a TypeScript loader.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `tsc` will only handle typescript and javascript files.

Consider using a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) if you want to bundle up other assets in your project